# Why do I get this error using Razorpay with Flutter=> Uncaught TypeError:window.getDeviceDetails is not a function and BAD_REQUEST_ERROR?

Tags: android, flutter, razorpay

I get the following error while using razorpay-flutter plugin for my flutter app:

```
I/chromium(13226): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: window.getDeviceDetails is not a function", source: https://api.razorpay.com/v1/checkout/public?version=1.5.16&platform=android&library=checkoutjs (1)
I/flutter (13226): Payment Error : 1 {"code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR","description":"The id provided does not exist","source":null,"step":null,"reason":null,"metadata":{}}
```

Description
Below is my complete Razorpay related code:

***Please note that if I remove the order ID from the options map below then it works fine,*** i.e. if I remove

```
'order_id': 'order_EMBFqjDHEEn80l',
```

from the code given below then, it works fine.

```
  FirebaseUser currentUser;
  DocumentSnapshot userDataFromFirebase;


  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();

    razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_SUCCESS, successHandler);
    razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_ERROR, failureHandler);
    razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_EXTERNAL_WALLET, externalWalletHandler);

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    razorpay.clear();
  }

  void openCheckout(double totalPrice) async{

    // finding current user
    currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    await Firestore.instance.collection('users').getDocuments().then((value){
      for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in value.documents){
        if(documentSnapshot.documentID == currentUser.phoneNumber.toString().substring(3)){
          userDataFromFirebase = documentSnapshot;
          break;
        }
      }
    });

    var options = {
      'key': 'rzp_test_CphmkEBGNw9BME', // my razorpay API test key
      'amount': totalPrice*100,
      'currency': 'INR',
      'name': 'Company name',
      'description': 'Payment to company',
      //'razorpay_order_id': 'order_EMBFqjDHEEn80l', // I used this as well but it didn't work
      'order_id': 'order_EMBFqjDHEEn80l', // just a random order ID for checking purposes (REMOVING THIS THE CODE WORKS FINE)
      'prefill': {
        'contact': ('+91'+ (await userDataFromFirebase.data['phoneNumber']).toString()).toString(),
        'email': (await userDataFromFirebase.data['email']).toString()
      },
    };

    try{
      razorpay.open(options);
    }
    catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  void successHandler(PaymentSuccessResponse response) {
    Toast.show("SUCCESS: " + response.paymentId, context,duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);

    razorpay.clear();
  }

  void failureHandler(PaymentFailureResponse response) {
    print('Payment Error : ${response.code.toString()} ${response.message.toString()}');
    Toast.show("ERROR: " + response.code.toString() + " - " + response.message, context,duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);

    razorpay.clear();
  }

  void externalWalletHandler(ExternalWalletResponse response) {
    print('External wallet ${response.walletName}');

    Toast.show("EXTERNAL_WALLET: " + response.walletName, context,duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);

    razorpay.clear();
  }
```

This is my complete response when I run the app:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Lenovo K33a42 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :cloud_firestore_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
Waiting for Lenovo K33a42 to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:36739/ZEVgbycZ38c=/ws
Syncing files to device Lenovo K33a42...
I/BiChannelGoogleApi(13226): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@35edc86
W/DynamiteModule(13226): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(13226): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(13226): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
V/NativeCrypto(13226): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(13226): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/ProviderInstaller(13226): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/art     (13226): Before Android 4.1, method double java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextDouble(double, double) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
W/art     (13226): Before Android 4.1, method int java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextInt(int, int) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
W/art     (13226): Before Android 4.1, method long java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextLong(long, long) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
I/BiChannelGoogleApi(13226): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@35edc86
D/FirebaseAuth(13226): Notifying id token listeners about user ( Iw8VCX0JHXaQmdsUYh6amXg0OrA2 ).
D/FirebaseAuth(13226): Notifying id token listeners about user ( Iw8VCX0JHXaQmdsUYh6amXg0OrA2 ).
V/BoostFramework(13226): mAcquireFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquire(int,int[])
V/BoostFramework(13226): mReleaseFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockRelease()
V/BoostFramework(13226): mAcquireTouchFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquireTouch(android.view.MotionEvent,android.util.DisplayMetrics,int,int[])
V/BoostFramework(13226): mIOPStart method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStart(int,java.lang.String)
V/BoostFramework(13226): mIOPStop method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStop()
V/BoostFramework(13226): BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@6e0b20
I/flutter (13226): pressed add
I/flutter (13226): pressed cart
I/flutter (13226): clicked on Proceed to pay
I/art     (13226): Do partial code cache collection, code=23KB, data=30KB
I/art     (13226): After code cache collection, code=19KB, data=28KB
I/art     (13226): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/WebViewFactory(13226): Loading com.android.chrome version 84.0.4147.125 (code 414712570)
I/cr_LibraryLoader(13226): Loaded native library version number "84.0.4147.125"
I/cr_CachingUmaRecorder(13226): Flushed 5 samples from 5 histograms.
W/ResourceType(13226): Failure getting entry for 0x7f130588 (t=18 e=1416) (error -2147483647)
W/ResourceType(13226): Attempt to retrieve bag 0x7f0c0000 which is invalid or in a cycle.
I/DpmTcmClient(13226): RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
W/cr_media(13226): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
E/libEGL  (13226): validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
I/chromium(13226): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: window.getDeviceDetails is not a function", source: https://api.razorpay.com/v1/checkout/public?version=1.5.16&platform=android&library=checkoutjs (1)
I/flutter (13226): Payment Error : 1 {"code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR","description":"The id provided does not exist","source":null,"step":null,"reason":null,"metadata":{}}
```

Expected Results:

I expect it to successfully complete the payment process and return the correct payment ID and Order ID.

I have opened an issue on the Github page of `razorpay_flutter` as well please check it out and help me solve this issue.

**Issue on Github page: https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-flutter/issues/98**

Comment: I have the same issue. in my case demo mode works perfectly fine and Live mode return this error

Answer (score 6):

Fortunately, I was able to solve the issue :)

For anyone who is not able to solve it yet, please read the Razorpay documentation as they are guiding developers to switch to the Orders API for generating their Order IDs. Please refer to this [Razorpay documentation](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/).

From what I have learned from it, you cannot generate a random Order ID (like "#ORD1") as per your convenience. You have to let Razorpay generate an Order ID for you by sending a request to them, something like this,

```
curl -u <YOUR_KEY_ID>:<YOUR_SECRET> \
-X POST https://api.razorpay.com/v1/orders \
-H "content-type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "amount": 50000,
  "currency": "INR",
  "receipt": "receipt#1",
  "payment_capture": 1
}'
```

I created a separate method to generate an Order ID for my application. Here it is,

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<String> generateOrderId(String key, String secret,int amount) async{
  var authn = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$key:$secret'));

  var headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': authn,
  };

  var data = '{ "amount": $amount, "currency": "INR", "receipt": "receipt#R1", "payment_capture": 1 }'; // as per my experience the receipt doesn't play any role in helping you generate a certain pattern in your Order ID!!

  var res = await http.post('https://api.razorpay.com/v1/orders', headers: headers, body: data);
  if (res.statusCode != 200) throw Exception('http.post error: statusCode= ${res.statusCode}');
  print('ORDER ID response => ${res.body}');

  return json.decode(res.body)['id'].toString();
}
```

Comment: http.post doesn't accept string url. Ir requires Uri. So for that, we can use as follows:  
     
 var url = Uri.parse('https://api.razorpay.com/v1/orders');
 var res = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: data);